# Linux cmd line, how do I move all found files to upper directory

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

What I want to do is to find certain files recursively and move them to the upper level of their current directories.

For example,

```
foo1/bar1/abc
foo2/bar2/bar3/abc
```

will be updated to

```
foo1/abc
foo2/bar2/abc
```

I tried

```
find -name \*abc -exec /bin/mv '{}' .. \;
```

But this is wrong since it moved everything to upper directory of `$PWD`.

Is there a similar cmd line way to move things dynamically up? Or do I have to use more complex scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go ..

This is what the structure looks like to begin with...

```
$ tree

[.]
 +-- foo1
 !   `-- bar1
 !       `-- abc
 !
 `-- foo2
     `-- bar2
         `-- bar3
             `-- abc
```

Then we run the command to move files

```
$ find . -type f -name "*abc" -exec bash -c ' mv -v  {} `dirname {}`/.. '  \;
```

This produces this output...

```
`./foo1/bar1/abc' -> `./foo1/bar1/../abc'
`./foo2/bar2/bar3/abc' -> `./foo2/bar2/bar3/../abc'
```

Now the directory structure looks like ..

```
$ tree

[.]
 +-- foo1
 !   +-- abc
 !   `-- bar1
 !
 `-- foo2
     `-- bar2
         +-- abc
         `-- bar3
```

the important bits ...

```
-type f        <-- Make sure that you pick files not folders, if you need folders too omit this.
-name "*abc"   <-- Your file-match pattern
-exec bash -c ' mv -v  {} `dirname {}`/.. '  \;
```

Here ..
Execute bash, pass it a string that will find the directory of the file and add a '/..' at the end to make the mv take the file to parent directory.

IMPORTANT WARNING:

> If you expect to have the file in the root of your search then
>   eventually the file will move to parent directory of your searching
>   root thereby taking them out of your match pattern forever.

OR

> If you are at the root of the filesystem the files will *always* match
>   and mv will become a no-op.

Anyway it will be good to test that you don't end up with files at the root, unless that is what the intention is. :-)

Hope this helps.